# SOAP:1.027 SRT: Serialization / Deserialization failed in ABAP Proxy

Tags: web-services, abap

I have to create a consumer proxy in SAP, the proxy generation is OK (or no errors were reported), but when i tried yo consume the proxy (SE80), i have the next error:

**SOAP:1.027 SRT: Serialization / Deserialization failed**

**System expected a value for the type g.**

[image: Error SAP - Customer Service]

If i continue, i have the response, but when i tried to call the customer service in a report, i have the error and i can't continue.
In a report, when i tried yo consume the proxy using this code, i have the same error, and i don't have response:

```
CREATE OBJECT proxy
  EXPORTING
    logical_port_name = 'LOGICAL_01'.

CALL METHOD proxy->proccess_check_status_invoice
  EXPORTING
    process_check_status_invoice   = input
  IMPORTING
    process_check_status_invoice_r = output.
```

Whow can i solve this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please use srt_util and verify the execution error with a trace of that proxy. The error log will specify which field and values are not allowed during the transformation.

SOAP:1.027 SRT: Serialization / Deserialization failed errors are due to incompatible data types, in my experience, most of the times are dates since ABAP datum and the standard differ and must be transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Type g is usually the constant for the TYPEKIND of STRING. My guess is you are binding values that are CHARs instead of the STRING datatype.